# Where is FileStream at the .NET for Windows Store?

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps

I'm creating a Windows Store app.
I need to create a FileStream in order to write some complex data for a proprietary file format. I add System.IO to my uses, but there's no FileStream available.

I've investigating some more, and the ".NET for Windows Store apps overview" guide talks about IsolatedStorage, which this library don't even use currently.
After some reading, I think the real replacement could be FileRandomAccessStream, from the nacemspace: Windows.Storage.Streams

What is the **real** equivalent to FileStream to use in a Windows Store app?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx#IO

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The disappearance of functionalility from the System.IO namespace caught me by suprise too. We are not degrading ourselves to newby bashing, are we?

Comment: @Dabblernl I came late to the party. I was working on a several big sharepoint projects last year and did not have time to try neither the VS2012 previews nor the Windows 8 previews. I now have to catch up and have been reading a lot of articles and the MSDN help these days and I see most articles are dated at near the beginning of 2102, even on late 2011, and all are full of comments and polemic. So, for all the folks that participated on that polemic, my question looks plain stupid and/or lazy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed, the sandbox has many limitations in where you can read from/write to. Here are some typical locations:

If you are trying to load resources from your **application's installation folder**, you can use the following:

- `StorageFolder installFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation`
- `StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appx:///file.txt");`

(It is a *read-only* folder, so you cannot edit or create new files.)

If you are trying to write data files to your **application's data folder**, you can use the following:

- `StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;`
- `StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appdata:///local/file.txt");`

(This folder is *read-write*. You can also access **roaming** or **temporary** folders by changing **local** to one of the other two.)

There are some other folders as well, such as the `DownloadsFolder`, although you can only access files that your application downloads.

Alternatively, you can always ask the user for permission with `FileOpenPicker` and `FileSavePicker`. The pickers do **not** allow access to the `InstalledLocation` path, but will allow you to access `Documents`, `Pictures`, and `Downloads` (even if your app did not download the file).

Comment: Great.  How do I use these objects with any function that uses a stream, such as serialization?

Answer (score 7):

Due to the sandbox environment Windows Store apps run in it has been replaced by `StorageFile`. See here for the documentation:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx