# Why I can't use FileStream in windows store app

Tags: c#

I'm writing windows store app in C# and I nead to open file (pic), so according to some samples it suppose to look like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)) 
        {
             ...
        }
```

But there is no any FileStream object, can anyone tell my why? And what else can I use?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx#IO

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758325.aspx

Comment: Store apps are sandboxed and thus don't have access to the entire .NET library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Where is FileStream at the .NET for Windows Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299410/where-is-filestream-at-the-net-for-windows-store) you have to use classes like `StorageFile` and `StorageFolder` to access files in Windows Store Apps.