# 'FileStream' Could not be found

Tags: c#, import, filestream

I'm getting the following error

```
The type or namespace name 'FileStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Note that I imported `System.IO` namespace and still have the error.

I also tried to explicitly qualify the type name `System.IO.FileStream`  and still get the error

```
public async void OnDataRead(byte[] c)
{
     using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\amirk_000\Pictures\n.png", FileMode.Append))
     {
          stream.Write(c, 0, c.Length);
     }
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that i am developing a windows store application

Comment: Adding "Urgent" to your title won't make things any faster for you.

Comment: Are you able to use other types in mscorlib.dll?

Comment: Oups. Thread.sleep() doesn't work for example.

Comment: See [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299410/where-is-filestream-at-the-net-for-windows-store)

Answer (score 5):

Your error message says `Filestream` (note that the 's' is lowercase). Most likely, you have a discrepancy between the code you're actually compiling, and the code you've shown here.

C# is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: I am using FileStream with upper case 'S' . I edited the post and copied the exact error message.

Comment: @user3426491 Please **always** copy and paste. Triva like this just waste's everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project references.  Have you got mscorlib.dll as a reference?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Checking the references depends on the type of Visual Studio Project.

For for every other type of project except Web Site projects, in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, simply expand the references folder within the project (at the top of the project).

For web site projects, right click on the project and select property pages.

Comment: How could i check ? i Forgot to mention that i'm developing a  Windows Store application

Comment: Updated my answer to include instructions on how to view project references