# FileStream class missing in Windows Phone 8 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm very new to Windows Phone development. I got an example project where I can start from. But when I copy a class I get strange errors.

I have for example this piece of code:

```
public async void WriteFileAsync(string jsonPath, string content)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(jsonPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    if (fs.CanWrite)
    {

        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(content);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have these usings:

```
using Cimbalino.Toolkit.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
```

But when I build I get errors on FileStream.

**ERROR**

> The type or namespace name 'FileStream' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you’re getting? It will be useful to anybody trying to help you.

Comment: Well, *are* you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: How do I know that ?

Comment: afaik FileStream isn't supported in Windows Phone 8 development. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299410/where-is-filestream-at-the-net-for-windows-store

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information for a proper answer but you should always try the follwing:

Check your refernces, is mscorlib set as a reference?
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Choose "Clean Solution" from the built options.

Create a Test class with the microsoft example (see link, just copy, paste).. does it compile?