# Local file storage during development of a Windows Store App

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

So I'm getting started in windows store apps.  It is also my first experience with Visual Studio.  Windows 8.1 for that matter, too :P

I'm trying to figure out how local file storage works during the dev phase of this project.  I understand the concept of how the appdata directory and the application install directory interact with the app once it is published and installed on a client's PC.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299721/2253532) SO answer gives a good overview of how it is supposed to work.  However, I can't figure out how, during development, I am supposed to use these concepts if the app isn't installed and doesn't have a dedicated folder in any of the appdata directories.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the app will be installed locally and the app's data will reside in some common place like `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\local\packages` during development. Check with the Packaging tab of your `Package.appxmanifest` file to determine the Package family name, it's probably going to be something cryptic. There'll be a corresponding folder in the `packages` folder.

One additional thing, though. There's a difference between an app that's been installed from an .appx file (e.g., through the store or side-loaded onto a device), and the type of installation that Visual Studio will perform for you when debugging. The latter is a so-called "unpackaged installation", and the application files that are part of your app package will be laid out slightly differently, with different implications. Most importantly, you will be able to modify the contents of files in your app package, which will fail for the same app when installed from an .appx. Also, you won't be able to install a packaged version of an app if an unpackaged install is present on the machine. (Of course, files in the `AppData` folder will behave the same way in either case.)

Comment: One more nuance here: In Windows Store apps, there is no notion of changing the "Current Working Directory". All relative paths are relative to the installed packaged directory which is as noted READ-ONLY in a real app. With universal Windows apps for Windows 10, the notion of changing the CWD is back because this proved too challenging for many older codebases that make heavy use of CWD. Always using absolute paths is more secure, but too painful for many codebases. Note that the actual permissions restrictions to the file system are unchanged for UWA/UWP.

Answer (score 2):

#### Where are the files ?

As @Chuck Walbourn mentionned your application should create any initial versions of `AppData` files and subdirectories it needs if they are not present.

Usually it resides in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\local\packages\EncryptedNameLinkedToYourApplication`

To be sure that it is really situated there add this line into your code and make sure your application executes it :

```
Dim folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

#### Use debugging

You can then do a **breakpoint** (click on the grayed out margin at the left of the newly added line of code).

Once the breakpoint is triggered hover your mouse over `folder` and a popup will appear. Inside that popup you can access the `path` property which will give you the full path of the local files on your computer.

You then know what is the "`EncryptedNameLinkedToYourApplication`" mentionned earlier

#### Too lazy to use a breakpoint?

Then, in your application, add 1 `button` and 1 `textbox`. On the click of the button you then want to add this code :

```
Dim folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
TextBoxTest.Text = folder.Path
```

Your textbox is now filled with the path to your local files including the encrypted application name

Comment: Never hardcode the paths. Always obtain the current appdata paths from the system at runtime, and reconstruct any needed directories/files if they are missing--possibly from read only 'starting' copies that are in your installed package.

Comment: He needed to know if the application had appdata files even if not installed and a solution to find them was provided. Not a solution to use them. Therefor the use of paths is not relevant in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you build and debug the Windows Store app, Visual Studio's deployment is installing the app and running it as if it were deployed through the Store or side-loaded.

As with User Account Controller, your application should create any initial versions of AppData files and subdirectories it needs if they are not present.

See [File access and permissions (Windows Runtime apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

**EDIT:** For Windows Store apps, you get the path to the directories you can use from `Windows::Storage::ApplicationData` and the `Current->LocalFolder`, `Current->RoamingFolder`, or `Current->TemporaryFolder` properties.

For Windows desktop apps, you used either the Windows 2000/XP `SHGetFolderPath` Win32 API or the Windows Vista era `IKnownFolder` COM API (which has an easier to use wrapper `SHGetKnownFolderPath`). The [Dual-use Coding Techniques for Games](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games-part-3.aspx) post shows some examples of writing both versions.

```
#include <wrl\client.h>

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

void GetApplicationDataDirectory(wchar_t* dir, size_t maxsize)
{
    if (!maxsize) return;
    *dir = 0;
#if !defined(WINAPI_FAMILY) || (WINAPI_FAMILY == WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP)
    // You can use the Win32 SHGetKnownFolderPath as well which is just
    // a wrapper that does the same thing.

    // On Windows XP, you use the older SHGetFolderPath function with
    // different constants that have the same meaning.

    ComPtr<IKnownFolderManager> mgr;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_KnownFolderManager,
        nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IKnownFolderManager, (LPVOID*) &mgr);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ComPtr<IKnownFolder> folder;
        hr = mgr->GetFolder(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, &folder);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            LPWSTR szPath = 0;
            hr = folder->GetPath(0, &szPath);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // A big different with Windows desktop apps is here.
                // With Windows Store apps, your appdata directory is 
                // isolated per-user and per-app. In Windows desktop,
                // it is only isolated per-user so you have to create
                // your own unique subdir and other Windows desktop apps
                // can mess with your data
                wcscpy_s(dir, maxsize, szPath);
                wcscat_s(dir, maxsize, L”\\MyUniqueApplicationName”);
                CreateDirectory(dir, nullptr);
                CoTaskMemFree(szPath);
            }
        }
    }
#else // Windows Store WinRT app
    auto folder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current
        ->LocalFolder;
    wcscpy_s(dir, maxsize, folder->Path->Data());
#endif
}
```