# Error: identifier :"SHGetKnownFolderPath" is unidentified

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a Windows Store app with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. My code is as follows:

```
#define WINVER 0x0A00
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#include <Shlobj.h>

...
HRESULT hr;
 hr= SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &tempPath);
```

I tried to adding above version and header files. still nothing changed.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this a windows store app?

Comment: Yes. it is windows app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) of the function, this function is available on the desktop only.

> **Minimum supported client**  Windows Vista [desktop apps only]

You are writing a store app, and so the function is not available to you.

Comment: In documentation, it is mentioned as 'desktop apps only' for Windows Vista. But im using OS Windows 10

Comment: No, it does not say that. It states that it is for desktop apps only, and for desktop apps the minimum supported platform is Vista. A store app is a store app, and that function is not available to store apps.

Comment: Yes. thank u. Any idea reg the equivalent for shgetknownfolderpath in Windows App??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533869/local-file-storage-during-development-of-a-windows-store-app

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation at MSDN. There, you will find both the required header and the required libs. Also, you will find the minimal system requirements (`WINVER` etc) that you seem to be aware of already.

Comment: Referred to documentation and added <Shlobj.h> header file. but still facing same issue.