# Targetting Windows 7 desktop: identifier "SHGetKnownFolderPath" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, header-files, appdata, shell32.dll

I am writing a C++ desktop app for Windows 7 and later.
I want to get the path to the AppData/Roaming folder so I use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>

void hello()
{
    LPWSTR roamingPath;
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, 0, NULL, &roamingPath);
```

**PROBLEM:** Build fails with `identifier "SHGetKnownFolderPath" is undefined`, which is strange as I think I included the right headers.

---

*Notes:*

- *Visual Studio 2015 tells me that my compile options are `/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\OverlayIcon.pch"`.*
- *Different from [Error: identifier :"SHGetKnownFolderPath" is unidentified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432213/error-identifier-shgetknownfolderpath-is-unidentified) where the problem is that the asker targets more than desktop.*

Comment: Your [target platform macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx) in your stdafx.h header are likely going to be important to this question, as their values indicate what features are exposed when compiling through the headers. May want to include those in your question.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Added! StackOverflow syntax problem though :-/

Comment: As it sits now after you updated your post it should at least compile the source. You own that stdafx.h header in your project btw. There is little sense in not just changing the values to the proper targets right there since it is included in all your translation units anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to add these two lines in your `stdafx.h` file:

```
#define WINVER 0x0601 // Allow use of features specific to Windows 7 or later.
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
```

This says that the app targets Windows 7, which is important because SHGetKnownFolderPath is only available from Windows Vista, as specified in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It did not work immediately for me, I had to clean up and even restart Visual Studio.

Here are the codes for all other versions of Windows:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

*Thanks to WhozCraig for the tip!*