# StreamReader in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to read from a XML file in Windows 10 Universal App. StreamReader only takes Stream as argument. I used to do this with the file path in WinForms, WPF or MVC but I don't know how to do it in Windows 10 universal app.

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SQLiteApp\SQLiteApp\SomeFile.xml");
```

[image]

Comment: You could just pass it a stream..

Comment: I think this is what your are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299410/where-is-filestream-at-the-net-for-windows-store

Comment: That is what I want to know how to do. I am searching but I was not successful

Comment: cool, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, Windows 10 and the sandbox has many limitations in where you can read from/write to.

This is not a Windows 10 App "Problem", but a **Windows Store App Api change.**
A common way to read a file in a Windows Store App is to use the `StorageFile`:

```
 StorageFile file = 
      await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appx:///yourFile.txt");
```

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299410/where-is-filestream-at-the-net-for-windows-store), to get more information about reading files in windows 10.